# Google App Engine database inconsistency

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter

Im writing a twitter app in Google App Engine. It accepts commands as Direct Messages, so i have setup a third party cronjob service to invoke a handler that processes DMs at regular intervals. I have a Model 'Info' that has just one entry, it stores some common data which are used in many places in the App(in this case, the time when the messages were processed recently). The general pattern of my handler is like this:

```
class Info(db.Model):
    msg_polled = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    .... More Properties ....

    @classmethod
    def get_info(cls):
        info = cls.all().get()
        if not info:
            info = cls()
            info.put()
        return info
---------------------------------------------------------
info = Info.get_info()
msgs = api.GetDirectMessages(since = info.msg_polled)
if not msgs:
    return
logging.info('Processing Messages since %s ' % str(info.msg_polled))
for msg in msgs:

    ...process commands...

    logging.info('Processed Message :- @%s : %s' % (msg.sender_screen_name, msg.text))

info.msg_polled = datetime.datetime.now()
info.put()
```

But sometimes i get logs like this :

```
I 03-30 07:50AM 10.973
Processing Messages since Sun, 29 Mar 2009 11:41:59 GMT 
I 03-30 07:50AM 11.122
Processed Message :- @foo : Foo_Bar
-------------------------------------------------------
I 03-30 07:46AM 08.014
Processing Messages since Sun, 29 Mar 2009 11:41:59 GMT 
I 03-30 07:46AM 08.130
Processed Message :- @foo : Foo_Bar
```

Here, it seems that info is not getting commited to the database. The message is processed multiple number of times, sometimes upto 10+ times before the msg_polled value changes. But i am not getting any Datastore exceptions. This happens only once in a while.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't show in your sample how you're retrieving info originally. Can you include that?

Comment: Also, the second set of log entries is dated _before_ the first set - was that intentional?

Comment: Sorry, i'll include that too.. and yes, the logs are in reverse chronological order..

Comment: Is it possible your script is timing out before reaching the put() at the end? I don't see any log entries to confirm that's not the case.

Comment: no.. iam not getting any TimeOut Exceptions, these are the only logs i get

Answer (score 0):

The Google AppEngine datastore uses BigTable under the covers, which is a distributed database system. Because of this, updates might not be visible immediately since the new data has not yet reached every distributed table (Amazon calls this "eventual consistency" in their SimpleDB). You should be fine after a few minutes.

Comment: But the docs have no mention of any such latency.. So, will reducing the frequency of the cronjob solve the problem?

Comment: I know, I searched for some links to support my story, but could find any. I'm sure I've read it somewhere, though.
Reducing the frequency could help, indeed. I suggest you give it a shot and see what happens. Let me know!

Comment: The cronjob is currently running once every 4min.. you can see this in the log time stamps.. dont you think 4min is a bit too long for that kind of a delay, even SimpleDB 'eventual consistency' delays are in the order of seconds right?

Comment: 4 minutes does sound a bit steep. Wouldn't know what else it could be.. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is good documentation about consistency in GAE datastore:

https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore

**The conclusion:**

Eventual consistency is an essential element of non-relational databases that allows developers to find an optimal balance between scalability, performance, and consistency. It is important to understand how to handle the balance between eventual and strong consistency to design an optimal data model for your application. In Google Cloud Datastore, the use of entity groups and ancestor queries is the best way to guarantee strong consistency over a scope of entities. If your application cannot incorporate entity groups because of the limitations described earlier, you may consider other options such as using keys-only queries or Memcache. For large applications, apply best practices such as the use of scattered IDs and reduced indexing to decrease the time required for consistency. It may also be important to combine Google Cloud Datastore with BigQuery to fulfill business requirements for complex queries and to reduce the usage of Google Cloud Datastore indexes as far as possible.